# Beginner guide for Activiti BPM?

Tags: grails, business-process-management, activiti, workflow-engine

I'm a beginner to Activiti BPM can any one suggest a good website(/Video) for configure and learn it..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember there were a book from Manning I think.

Yes, this one
[Activity in Action](http://www.manning.com/rademakers2/)

Comment: http://www.activiti.org/userguide/  - **Activiti 5.12 User Guide**
https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/tree/master/modules - **activiti modules source code**

Answer (score 1):

You can also check this book "Activiti 5.x Business Process Management Beginner's Guide".